# Variable data-type for object's property instead of property's value?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, variables, types

Does there exist a data-type for expressing object properties as a variable? i.e. `TextBox1.Text` as variable?

I'm not attempting to achieve its text as a string data-type variable nor the control as an object data-type. Instead, I'm trying to achieve...

```
Dim userCountry As String
favouriteCar = ComboBox1.Text

Dim mostPopularCar As ?
mostPopularCar = TextBox1.Text

Select Case userCountry
    Case "Canada"
        mostPopularCar = "Hyundai"
    Case "USA"
        mostPopularCar = "Ford"
    Case "China"
        mostPopularCar = "Volkswagon"
    Case "Uganda"
        mostPopularCar = "Toyota"
End Select
```

Ultimately, rather than writing `TextBox1.Text` =, I'd like to write `mostPopularCar =`.

...or, am I simply simply going too far in defining any variables at all when all I really need to do is append .Text to each iteration of each object?

Comment: so what you want to do, is work with a reference to the Textbox1.Text property and not the value of the property?  
Anyway in this example you are right, using the "MostPopularCar" variable is an Overkill, because you don't want to do something with the read value, you just want to change it.

Comment: @lsteinme Correct. As per the above example, rather than writing `TextBox1.Text =`, I'd like to write `mostPopularCar =`. Also note my final inquiry (see last sentence).

Comment: @lsteinme Just noticed your edit. Thanks for clarifying that it's overkill. That's all I really need to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this, if you really want to use a varibale (maybe because you want to save the old value or do something depending on it)

```
Sub whatever()
        Dim userCountry As String = "USA"
        changeText(Textbox1.Text, userCountry)
    End Sub

    Private Sub changeText(ByRef mostPopularCar As String, userCountry As String)
        Select Case userCountry
            Case "Canada"
                mostPopularCar = "Hyundai"
            Case "USA"
                mostPopularCar = "Ford"
            Case "China"
                mostPopularCar = "Volkswagon"
            Case "Uganda"
                mostPopularCar = "Toyota"
        End Select
    End Sub
```

Comment: Considering that the purpose of defining the property as a variable was to simplify my code, the available solution (what you've provided), seems to introduce greater complexity than not defining the property as a variable. As per your comment, I'll forgo the "overkill" of defining the property as a variable and just write it in its full form (`Object.Property = "String"`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough (at least for me).

but if i understood you correctly, you can use System.Reflection.PropertyInfo type to access object's properties by their names
i.e.

```
Dim textProperty As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo = TextBox1.GetType().GetProperty("Text")
Dim textValue As String = textProperty.GetValue(TextBox1)
```

Comment: I've added an additional sentence for clarity. See second last line (begins with "Ultimately").

Comment: You can use my posted code in the previous answer and use textProperty.SetValue method to assign the value